# Crossrider - send window url from sidebar to remote database

Tags: php, jquery, crossrider

In Crossrider, I am creating an extension with the sidebar plugin.

The sidebar has the ability to specify a url

//url:'http:// site.com', // URL of the iframe that will show inside the sidebar (your site's content)

Would like to have this as a variable based on the window url.

example

sidebar content server is at server.com/content.php

user is browsing on example.com

Sidebar would automatically direct to server.com/content.php?www_example_com

When user moves to a different page, example2.com, the sidebar would automatically reload with http://www.server.com/content.php?www_example2_com

Last but not least, have been reading up on XSS, should this use encode / decode as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite simply even without using a variable and I've added a param name (**q**) as is the norm when using URL parameters, as follows:

```
url: 'http://www.server.com/content.php?q=' + location.hostname.replace(/\./,"_"),
```

Regarding using encode, technically URL components should be encoded using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), i.e. `encodeURIComponent(location.hostname.replace(/\./,"_"))`.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]